# React setState callback and render execution order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In Reactjs after invoking setState which method will call first. setState callback or render function?

Comment: render method. Why don't you console.log in those resp functions and check for yourself!

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle Thanks. I thought those were asynchronous operations

Comment: setstate is asyn only, in both functional and class-based components!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render first, then setState callback. SetState is async in the sense that it will wait for the render to finish to execute the callback. You can find more info here : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate